# Grub: No such partition

Tags: grub2

I installed kali alongside ubuntu but I formatted the kali drive.
I reinstalled grub using the following command:
`grub-install /dev/sda`
Now when I boot, I get `No such partition` error.
I did the following steps in grub rescue console:

```
set prefix=(hd0,2)/boot/grub
set root=(hd0,2)
insmod normal
normal
```

After that it successfully booted into the Ubuntu installation but I have to do it every time device boots up.
How to fix this problem permanently?

Comment: Did you do `sudo grub-install /dev/sda`? And is system booting from sda? Otherwise: May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: @oldfred Yes, I did `sudo grub-install /dev/sda` again. but it didn't fix the problem. I booted into a live usb ubuntu, then installed Boot-Repair, and clicked on creating summery. Here is the results: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/SWzT8s6W7Y/

Comment: You show mount in fstab of two different data partitions, one data and on Data. And UUIDs are different but one has an UUID that does not exist. You have to fix that to get system to boot. Do not see anything else. After fixing fstab, I might just use Boot-Repair to reinstall grub. If still errors post a new link to a new report.

Comment: @oldfred Thank you. It fixed it.